# FInding stationary points of Logistic regression with cross-entropy loss

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, cross-entropy

Let's say that I want to find the stationary points of the Cross-Entropy Loss function when using a logistic regression

The 1 D logistc function is given by :
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\begin{split}
\sigma(wx) = \frac{1}{1+\exp{(-wx)}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

and the cross entropy loss is given by :

\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
\begin{split}
\textbf{L}(wx) = -y \log{(\sigma(wx))} - (1-y) \log{(1-\sigma(wx))}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

When I simplify and differentiate and equal to 0, I find the following:

\begin{equation}\label{eq7}
\begin{split}
\frac{d\textbf{L}}{dw} &= (1-y)x - \frac{xe^{-wx} }{1+e^{-wx}} = 0\\
(x-xy)*(1+e^{-wx}) &=xe^{-wx} \\
(1-y)(1+e^{-wx}) &= e^{-wx}\\
1  +e^{-wx} -y- ye^{-wx} &= e^{-wx}\\
1-y - ye^{-wx}& = 0\\
1-y & = ye^{-wx}\\
\frac{(1-y)}{y} &= e^{-wx}\\
w &= - \frac{\log(\frac{(1-y)}{y})}{x}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

However, this is very weird and strongly feels very wrong:

- First x cannot be equal to 0
- Second, y cannot be equal to 0
- Third, y cannot be equal to 1

1 and 0 are the only values that y takes in a cross-entropy loss, based on my knowledge.
I am not sure where I left the right track.

I know that cross-entropy loss means there are 2 loss (one for each value of y) but I am not sure if that plays in the steps and if yes, how?
Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your primary problem is trying to do this for a *single* $y$, which has to be 0 or 1, and which gets you into domain problems.  The actual loss is a sum over observations with different $x$s and $y$s -- and that matters.  Even in the simple case with a single binary $x$, you'll end up with some 0s and some 1s for $y$ for each value of $x$, and that avoids the division by zero problems.  If your training data **were** all 0 or all 1, you would get this sort of breakdown

Comment: I am not sure to understand. Sorry. Do you mean I should do the same process but for the loss function when y=0 and then when y=1?

Comment: No. The loss for $n$ observations is $\sum_{i=1}^n L(wx_i,y_i)$.  That's what you have to minimise -- and that won't have the division by zero problems.

Comment: That's what I did. To minimize the loss, we need to differentiate with respect to w and $=0$. I don't see what you mean if you are saying to do something else.

Comment: You have only one observation, not sum of the loss over multiple observations. It matters.

Comment: ok, @ThomasLumley. I see. So you mean that when I add all the data points for the formula that I got, I won't have the division by zero problems anymore, is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115210/discussion-between-lalaland-and-thomas-lumley).